# Three js Access objects contained in an obj file

Tags: javascript

I need to load an obj file and apply different materials to the parts contained in the obj file in a second moment.

I load the OBJ file with this code using the OBJLoader i found in threejs examples:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( '../includes/open.obj', function ( object ) {
    console.log(object);
    object.name = "object_name";
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        }
    } );
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

I' m able to assign a material to the whole obj model, but I can't assign different materials to the parts of the model.

I tryed to check the object structure in the console, but it results just one child.

Looking to OBJLoader2 it seems that code it should returns the parts of the models in different objects, but it gives me an error on line 185 of three.min.js "undefined is not a function".

Someone can help me? I really can't solve.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding question correctly, so please let me know if this is not the answer you were looking for.

Please modify material attribute of each child.

```
var childCounter = 0;
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( '../includes/open.obj', function ( object ) {
    console.log(object);
    object.name = "object_name";
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
        if(childCounter == 0) {
            child.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, shading: THREE.FlatShading} );
        }
        else {
            child.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5} );
        }
        child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        scene.add(child);
        childCounter++;
    }
} );
```

} );